# Continuous functions and closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Good day,

If a set $X \subset \Bbb R$ is topologically closed, and a function $f:X \to Y$ is continuous, why is the set $Y \subset \Bbb R$ also closed?

Best wishes

Comment: This isn't true. As a counterexample, consider the arctan function. The image of arctan is $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ which is open.

Comment: That's true. I'm a bit confused because I'm asked to prove that if a function is continuous and if its image is closed, then its pre-image is also closed. I couldn't see a way to do it.

Comment: But that's different: the preimage of a closed set under a continuous map is closed, but not necessarily conversely. Furthermore, the *image* of $X$ under $f$ might not be all of $Y$, so you can't conclude much about $Y$.

Comment: The preimage of any closed set will be closed if $f$ is continous.

Comment: @BrianO why does the converse not hold?

Comment: By "converse" I mean, it's not necessarily true that the continuous image of a closed set is closed. There are continuous functions that map $\Bbb R$, which is closed, **and* open, *onto* an open interval. @aaron's example (arctan) is one. There are also rational functions with the same property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are saying is actually that a continuous function must be an open function. Unfortunately this is not true. By open function, it means a function maps any open set(closed set) to open set(closed set).

Comment: An open function maps open sets to open sets but it does not necessarily maps closed sets to closed sets. This latter property defines closed functions. In other words, an open function needs not to be closed.